# How to remove [Gmail] folder in MS outlook 2010?

Tags: microsoft-office, microsoft-outlook-2010

I am using MS Outlook 2010 and configured Gmail accounts.It lists all configured account folders as follows

```
[Gmail]
  All mails
  Drafts
  Important
  Spam
  Starred
  Trash
```

How to remove [Gmail] folders (or) how to get out sent items,trash etc from [Gmail] folders.If any one know help me.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure why you would want to do that, as this is how GMail represents your default folders and labels, when connecting through IMAP.

The beauty of this is, that moving mails between the IMAP folders in Outlook, marking mails as read etc., will also be reflected when using webmail, smartphones and other IMAP clients.

If you do not want this, I think your only option is to configure Outlook to use POP3, rather than IMAP, to get your GMail.

As far as I remember, you can't change an IMAP account to a POP3 account in Outlook. You'll have to create a new account, manually specifying server settings.

Comment: When manually setting up Outlook for GMail, you can use the following [this guide](https://support.google.com/mail/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=77689), as Outlook 2007 is not much different from 2010.

Just remember to set account type to POP3 instead of IMAP and enter server 'pop.gmail.com'. Click 'More settings', switch to the Advanced tab and check to use SSL for POP3. The port number should change to 995.

Comment: Feel free to upvote/mark as answer, if you feel your question has been answered. That will also clean your question out of the "unanswered" list.

Answer (score 0):

Create a new POP3 account in Outlook. As soon as it is created, disconnect the internet.

Click File -> Options -> Advanced. Click Send/Receive button.

Select Edit, then your account, then account properties. In the advanced tab check "Leave a copy on the server".

Now, re-connect the internet and send / receive. It could take a long time depending on how many emails you have.

You will now be downloading a copy from Gmail without syncing (meaning, if you were to delete an email in Outlook, it still exists on the server).

The negative is, no syncing, so if you send an email via Outlook, it will only appear in the sent folder in Outlook, and not in Gmail.

Any way, if this has solved the problem, go back to accounts and remove the original IMAP account. If not, then delete this new pop3 account.